# Android "achartengine" points on Y-axis

Tags: android, gridview, achartengine

I am using "achartengine" in android for chart, in that I want points on `Y-axis` as `0,0.5,1.0,1.5` instead of `0,1,2,3,4`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the value you set using `renderer.setYLabels()` until it displays what you need.

Or you can add custom labels:

```
renderer.addYTextLabel(0.5, "0.5");
```

Comment: its setting the string "0.5"  value at 0.5 only. i want that there is a series in my case like 0,2,4,8..which is coming by default but i want the series to be like 0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0... using same spacing.

Comment: Is it really difficult to do a for loop and call renderer.addYTextLabel for several values?